# Laravel whoops and class str not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to update my Laravel from 5.4 to 5.5 but I am having some errors-

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler::setApplicationPaths() in...

Laravel log shows something like this-

> production.ERROR: Class 'str' not found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Class 'str' not found at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\config\cache.php:91) [stacktrace]
>
> production.ERROR: Class 'str' not found {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Class 'str' not found at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\config\cache.php:91) [stacktrace]

This is how my cache.php looks-

```
'prefix' => env(
    'CACHE_PREFIX',
    str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'
 ),
```

The line 91 is the str::slug. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Did you follow the official upgrade guide? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0

Comment: Yes sir. and also a tuturial on youtube and still i have miss this :$

Comment: did you run `composer update`?

Comment: yes i had and now i have try to clean the cache for exemple and gives error in cache line 91 class str not found

Comment: add the `config/cache.php` line 91 to you question please

Comment: I have update my question and add config/cache.php

Comment: try to change `str::slug` with `str_slug` please

Comment: still same error

Comment: same error on the same file and on same line?

Comment: sorry it is working =) the error was on session same thing i have replate str::slug with str_slug.

Comment: Thanks it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your string function call like one of these-

```
str_slug('your_string');
```

Or this

```
use Str;

Str::slug('your_string');
```

Make sure to run this once you make changes in your config files so your config changes can be cached again and work as intended-

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `Str` in blade templates you can add to `app.php`

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Str', 'Str');
```

or for newer versions to alias section in `config/app.php`

```
'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
```

and `{{ Str::slug('your_string') }}` becomes available/